# What is the correct way to return a nested collection from a object?

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following class

```
class Person{
 long id;
 List<Address> addresses;

 public Person(long id){
  this.id = id;
  this.addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
 }

 public long getId(){
  return id;
 }

  //Implementation # 1
  public List<Address> getAddresses(){
    List<Address> addressesToReturn = new ArrayList<Address>();
    for(Address address : addresses){
    addressesToReturn.add(address.copy());
    }
    return addressesToReturn;
  }
}


class Address{
  String value;

  public Address(String value){
    this.value = value;
  }

  public Address copy(){
    Address address = new Address(this.value);
    return address;
  }
}
```

In this particular case, `getAddresses()` returns a list of copies of address object. I could have had two alternate implementations as follows:

```
  //Implementation # 2
  public List<Address> getAddresses(){
    List<Address> addressesToReturn = new ArrayList<Address>();
    for(Address address : addresses){
    addressesToReturn.add(address); //i.e. return the original object as is
    }
    return addressesToReturn;
  }
```

OR

```
  //Implementation # 3
  public List<Address> getAddresses(){
    return addresses; //i.e return the original list.
  }
```

Now, I see that I should not be using the 3rd implementation as I do not want some external code to change addresses of the Person object.

Between the first and the second, I am a bit confused. Which of the first two implementations is preferred, especially when I will have some sort of datastore/database to store all the person object?

I would like to know when to use the `Implementation # 1` and when to use `Implementation # 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if `Address` has `setValue`, you should use Implementation #1; otherwise, Implementation #2 will work fine, because your `Address` objects are immutable.

Note that you do not necessarily want to use the more expensive solution #1 even if the `Address` itself is mutable. Another alternative is to present mutable `Address` instances as an immutable interface, and return the list of objects implementing that interface. This would let you avoid copying the individual objects:

```
public interface Address {
    String getAddress();
}
class AddressImpl implements Address {
    String address;
    public AddressImpl(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getAddress() { return address; }
    public void setAddress(String address) { this.address = address; }
}
...
public List<Address> getAddresses(){
    List<Address> addressesToReturn = new ArrayList<Address>();
    for(Address address : addresses){
        addressesToReturn.add(address); //i.e. return the original object as is
    }
    return addressesToReturn;
}
```

Comment: this interface based solution is really sexy! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The (important) aspect of mutability/immutability of the `Address` class was already mentioned in other answers.

You already mentioned that the third implementation (returning the original list) should NOT be used in general, to prevent external code from modifying the list. But this goal can also be achieved by creating an unmodifiable view:

```
//Implementation #4
/**
 * Returns an unmodifiable view on the list of addresses
 * ...
 */
public List<Address> getAddresses(){
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(addresses);
}
```

Note that the comment may be important: When someone receives an unmodifiable *view* on the list, he has to assume that the backing list might change while he holds a reference to this view.

Unfortunately, there is a slight trade-off between "hiding implementation details" and "specifying the method precisely"...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
List<String> listCopy = new ArrayList(list);
```

`listCopy` would be independent from `list`.